# regex | match first pattern | and stop if not matched

Tags: regex

String to be matched:

```
id=abc somethingelse value=1 value=2 value=3 value=1
```

String not to be matched:

```
id=abc somethingelse value=2 value=2 value=3 value=1
```

I would like to:

- skip the `somethingelse` string, i.e., can't predict what this string is, so must use wildcard
- match the first occurrence `value=1`
- if the first `value` does not equal to 1, ignore any other occurrences
  and abort. So the second example should not be matched.

I tried `id=abc.*?value=1` in regex101, but obviously it doesn't stop at the first value...

Many thanks.

Comment: So for the first string, you want two separate matches of `id=abc` and `value=1` ("skip the somethingelse"?), and for the second, you want no matches at all, is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex with negative lookahead:

```
^id=abc(?:(?!value=).)*value=1
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uv9h6T/3)

Key part is use of `(?:(?!value=).)*` which means match any character as long as it is not followed by `value=` (enforced by negative lookahead `(?!value=)`).

Comment: This is awesome. Works like a charm!! Noted! Thank you so much